# pytest testing functions with known result

Tags: python, pytest

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class SimpleClass:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value

    def power_value(self, power):
        return self.value**power
```

I will create an instance of this class.

```
x = SimpleClass(2)
```

I want to create a test that will assert that the `power_value` method works fine by comparing it with the expected result.

```
def test_power_value(simple, power, result):
    assert simple.power_value(power) == result
```

I am looking for the right way to implement this with `pytest` since, the way I'm doing it, it throws me an error (`pytest` is looking for `simple`, `power` and `result` to be fixtures). Ultimately, I would like to be able to use this test as follow:

```
test_power_value(x, 2, 4)

with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
    test_power_value(x, 2, 5)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're using Python 2.7.x, properties only work correctly with new style classes (classes inheriting from `object`). Also, you should probably use a "protected" attributes (single leading underscore) - the double leading underscore stuff is really for preventing accidental name clashes in base classes of complex libs/frameworks, and is actually very seldom useful.

Comment: what's wrong with defining fixtures? also your `with pytest.raises(AssertionError)` block doesn't make any sense because you've tested already that result is equal to 4, it can't (or, if you have somehow overridden `__eq__` method, shouldn't) be equal to 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are defining as "test_power_value" would not really be a test but a helper function in pytest.

In pytest you run test functions in your code - pytest executes the tests for you - that's why it's looking for the fixtures. Just rename your function so it does not start with "test"

```
def assert_power_value(simple, power, result):
    assert simple.power_value(power) == result
```

And the you can use that in test:

```
def test_foo():
    x = 1
    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
        assert_power_value(x, 2, 5)
```

and ten run your tests:

```
pytest your_test_file.py
```